# Groovy shows java.io.NotSerializableException when making prepared statement

Tags: sql, groovy, xmlslurper

When executing the following piece of code:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(url)
title = rss.chanel.title
rss.channel.item.each {
   sql.firstRow("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news WHERE title = ? ", [it.title])
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException
```

What may cause it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that `it.title` was a NodeChild object.

In order to get the serializable text of this object I had to use `it.title.text()`. It was quite tricky since I could use `print it.title` successfully

Comment: Because for `NodeChild` `toString()` method returns its value. This is how it work in groovy and is very, very good.